# Add some data to extra_context in response_change

Tags: django

I have some model:

```
from django.db import models


class Deviation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def calc(self):
        # some calculation
        return 1
```

Then I added a button that runs `calc` method (overrided change form):

```
{% extends 'admin/change_form.html' %}

{% block submit_buttons_bottom %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <div class="submit-row">
            <input type="submit" value="Calculate" name="calc">
    </div>
    Calculation result: {{ result }}
{% endblock %}
```

This model is registered in admin with handling `calc` button submit (pass result in `extra_context`):

```
@admin.register(Deviation)
class DeviationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_form_template = 'admin/deviations_change_form.html'
    list_display = '__str__',

    def response_change(self, request, obj):
        if "calc" in request.POST:
            obj.save()
            result = obj.calc()
            return self.change_view(request, str(obj.id), form_url='', extra_context={'result': result})
        return super().response_change(request, obj)
```

Here problem (recursion) happening. I cannot render change view with result through `extra_context`.

How can I pass extra_context to change view?

Answer (score 0):

based on your code I assume you want to show something on the admin change form from response_change

Rendering on successful POST request is considered an anti-pattern as the form can be resubmitted if refreshed or when the user presses the back button on the browser

The maximum recursion error is because the method change_view internally calls response_change and in your code response_change method is calling change_view again which results in recursion without exit condition or return

**We can use Django cache for showing extra content on redirect without rendering like below**

**1) First setup CACHES in settings.py**

```py
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        'LOCATION': 'unique-snowflake',
    }
}
```

Refer this document for other types of [Django Caches](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/cache/)

**2) Use django cache in response_change like below**

```py
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

@admin.register(Deviation)
class DeviationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ....

    def response_change(self, request, obj):
        if "calc" in request.POST:
            obj.save()
            result = obj.calc()

            # Caching results with unique key 
            # In the format result_<object_id>
            # timeout is optional
            cache.add("result_%s" % obj.id, result, timeout=30)

            return HttpResponseRedirect(".")
        return super().response_change(request, obj)
    ....
```

**3) Now overide the change method to read from cache and pass extra_content**

```py
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

@admin.register(Deviation)
class DeviationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ....

    def change_view(request, object_id, form_url="", extra_content={}):
        # Retrieving results from Django cache
        results = cache.get("result_%s" % object_id)
        if results:
            extra_content.update({"results":"results")
        return super().change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_content)

    def response_change(self, request, obj):
        if "calc" in request.POST:
            obj.save()
            result = obj.calc()
            
            # Caching results with unique key 
            # In the format result_<object_id>
            # timeout is optional
            cache.add("result_%s" % obj.id, result, timeout=30)
            
            return HttpResponseRedirect(".")
        return super().response_change(request, obj)
    ....
```

I hope this helps someone, thank you.